# Push to bitbucket repo without creating a merge commit

Tags: git, commit, bitbucket, rebase

On bitbucket I have `ProjectA`.

I have a fork of `ProjectA` that i'll refer to as `forkProjectA`

When on my local machine I have 2 remotes

```
origin  #forkProjectA
upstream #ProjectA
```

Then pretend I do something like

```
git pull origin master
git checkout -b newFeature
#implement feature
git commit -am "finished feature"
```

And now I want to push branch newFeature to upstream (`ProjectA`) branch newFeature without making a merge commit.

The ones that have a message like

`Merge branch 'newFeature' of bitbucket.org:user/projectA into 'newFeature'`

In some cases I'd like to avoid doing a pull request to the upstream simply because of the merge commit.  Looking back through the history of ProjectA, it looks horrible with every other commit being one of those nasty "Merge this into that pull request #192382" messages
I'm pretty sure through their website there is no way to do this (merge without the merge commit message) but there should be through the command line right?

I think it may involve a rebase, but I don't know a lot about them and am scared.

Can someone give me the command to merge my local/newFeature to upstream/newFeature without the creation of a merge commit?

Comment: Why are you scared about a rebase? Do you want only to merge the branch locally and then push it to upstream right?

Comment: basically just scared of screwing something up/losing data.  Rebasing when you don't fully understand what's going on seems dangerous.  All i'm looking to do is a merge a local branch to upstream an upstream branch (possibly with different name) without having the extra merge commit tacked on.